# Determine the audio frequency of sound received via the microphone

Tags: android, signal-processing

I am trying to understand how to go about determining the frequency of various sounds captured on the phone via microphone.

I am attempting to display a graph plotting the frequency of the note.

Comment: "_The_ frequency" is very, very unlikely to happen. Even if you played a pure tone (which is already physically impossible), the microphone would capture a noisy variant thereof, with multiple frequencies. How familiar are you with signal processing theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "notes" produced by most musical instruments may contain spectral content at a large number of frequencies.  Furthermore the frequency spectrum of a "note" may or may not contain significant peaks at what a human would call the musical pitch of the note.  So you may not even be asking the correct question.

There's more commentary on this issue in one answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447059/auriotouch-fft-for-an-instrument-tuner).

A spectrograph (via repeated usage of an FFT or other filter bank) is a common technique for displaying, in graphic form plotted against time, the frequencies contained in captured sound, with a trade-off in time response versus frequency resolution.

There's example spectrograph code in Apple's [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app available from the iOS Developer web site.

Answer (score 1):

Record the audio stream and count number of Zero crossing. That should give you the frequency.
But cautious in choosing the appropriate sampling rate.

Comment: on what base should I choose appropriate sampling rate?

Comment: I would follow the [Nyquist Frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) which indicates that the sampling rate should be **twice** the highest frequency. So somehow determine a way of finding the highest frequency (Maybe you already know it, maybe you can just update it as you read frequencies), and make your sampling rate twice that.